# Website breaks on mobile as soon as mobile script is added

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am using mobile script from website http://mobilizejs.com/, it works for my other website.

My exiting website has a js function like

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++)
  {
    var anchor = $( anchors[i] );
    if (anchor.getAttribute("href") && anchor.getAttribute("rel") == "external")
    {
```

and when i add js from mobilizejs like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mobilizejs.com/releases/0.1/js/mobilize.core.min.js"></script>
```

Mobile website breaks and i get js error like

```
anchor.getattribute is not a function
```

Any ways to solve this error.

Comment: what is on your `mobilize.options` whitelist?

Comment: @ahren - i did not get to know. what ur asking about.

Comment: http://cdn.mobilizejs.com/docs/trunk/manual/development.html

Comment: @ahren - K i just saw that now. You mean to say it cleans up all the website related js rite.

Comment: Yes. I've never used mobilize.js before, but from the documentation, I'd assume so, yes.

Comment: @ahren - Ok. Any other such script that can be used?

Comment: not that I know of. I tend to just use mobile-first media-queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making jQuery objects from anchors and jQuery objects has no `getAttribute` method. as you are using jQuery you can use `each` and `attr` methods. Try the following:

```
var anchors = $('a')
anchors.each(function(i, v){
   if ($(this).attr('rel') == 'external') {
       // do something here
   }
})
```

Comment: The website works properly. But when i add the mobile script it breaks, thats what has kept me wondering.

Comment: I am not allowed to change that script, as it is maintained by other group. When i run it normally, there is no javascript error and only when i add that Mobile script the website breaks and gives javascript error.

Comment: @Hacker as far as I know the written code should not work, and the console correctly shows what is wrong.

Comment: But the code i have posted is just in javascript rather then jquery, you may be ignoring that point

Comment: `var anchor = $( anchors[i] )` - you're wrapping it in a jQuery object here.